# How to send multiple file like .txt to Telegram via Curl

Tags: bash, curl, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to send multiple messages such as two text files to Telegram via Curl. It works fine if it would be only one Txt file, but if I'd like to send two Txt files it'll be don't work.
I also tried that thing, but not work:

```
curl -X POST -F "chat_id=-CHAT_ID" \
     -F "document=@/tmp/test/1.txt" \
     -F "document=@/tmp/test/2.txt" \
     https://api.telegram.org/API_TOKEN/sendDocument
```

The command works fine without any error, But only the first Txt file is sent. There's no second Txt file.
Any idea? Thanks for your helps.

Comment: This might help: [send multiple files to a telegram channel in a single message using bot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74851187/3776858)

Comment: Not bad, but I'd like to do that in bash.

Comment: Use two curl commands?

Comment: I'm looking for tricks to do it by using one Curl command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendDocument` can only send a single file.

You'll need to use [`sendMediaGroup`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmediagroup) to send multiple files with a single CURL command.

Then pass the data as multipart/form-data, in the following format:

```
[{ "type": "document", "media": "attach://file1" }, ...]
```

For more info please read the [inputMediaDocument documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputmediadocument).

---

So an example curl command will look like:

```bash
curl -F "chat_id=13245679" \
     -F 'media=[{"type": "document", "media": "attach://file1"}, {"type": "document", "media": "attach://file2" }]' \
     -F "file1=@/tmp/test1.txt" \
     -F "file2=@/tmp/test2.txt" \
     "https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOT-TOKEN>/sendMediaGroup"
```

Which will result in a mediaGroup containing those 2 files:

[image]